# How to correctly reference a double pointer inside a structure using malloc

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, malloc

I have written a function that parses a url and splits it into it's components. To store the components of the URL, I pass a pointer (to the function) to the following structure called urlinfo:

```
typedef struct urlstruct {
    char** protocol;
    char** address;
    char** port;
    char** page;
} urlstruct;
```

The reason for it containing double pointers is because I don't know how long each components of the URL will be. Inside the function, I work out the size needed to store each component and attempt to assign the memory to the components of the urlstruct using the following line:

```
*(urlinfo->protocol) = (char*)malloc(i * sizeof(char));
```

where `(i * sizeof(char))` is the size required. This line causes an access violation. Does anyone know how to correctly allocate the memory?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Almost certainly, `urlinfo->protocol` isn't a valid pointer. How did you initialise it? (By the way, you never need to multiply by `sizeof(char)`, since by definition it is 1).

Comment: I don't understand your need for double pointers. A `char*` is all you need if the components are single C strings (of whatever length).

Comment: considering this is tagged as c++: do you have pressing reasons to use raw pointers and malloc for memory management (meaning you pass it to a library which expects `malloced` pointers)?  If not I would suggesting avoiding that. And why exactly do you need the double pointers? It doesn't seem like you have multiple protocols, ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're really using C++, you should instead just have:

```
struct urlstruct {
    std::string protocol;
    std::string address;
    std::string port;
    std::string page;
};
```

Then filling it becomes easy:

```
url.protocol = "http://";
```

And you don't have to worry about anything else.

But, if your tag is wrong and you really need cstrings for some reason:

```
typedef struct {
    char* protocol;
    char* address;
    char* port;
    char* page;
} urlstruct;
```

You only need single pointers. You can then allocate memory for them in very close to the same way you already are:

```
char* proto = "http://" //Assuming you get this from somewhere
int len = strlen(proto) + 1;
urlstruct url;
url.protocol = malloc(len * sizeof(char));
```

Comment: My C++ tag is correct, I am just in the habit of using CStrings because one of the books I learnt from was particuarly old. I will try to use std::string's from now on though :) Thanks for your answer

Comment: For C++, you'll need to either cast the result of `malloc`, or use `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pointers to pointers.  Declare your structure like this:

```
typedef struct urlstruct {
    char* protocol;
    char* address;
    char* port;
    char* page;
} urlstruct;
```

Then allocate them like this:

```
urlinfo->protocol = (char*)malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Your pointers to pointers are an unneeded complication, and mean you have to allocate two items.  You are skipping one of those allocations, which is why you have an access violation.